# How to display json values that are in 2nd level of a multi-dim array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Having a problem on solving this code. These are the arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => delux
            [price] => 213
            [description] => 
            [tv] => 0
            [breakfast] => 0
            [park] => 0
            [wifi] => 0
            [ac] => 0
            [occupancy] => 
            [size] => 
            [view] => 
            [service] => 
            [terrace] => 0
            [pickup] => 0
            [internet] => 0
            [gym] => 0
            [note] => 
            [room_details] => {"img":["images/logo2.png","images/logo.png"]}
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => hjghj
            [price] => 234
            [description] => 
            [tv] => 0
            [breakfast] => 0
            [park] => 0
            [wifi] => 0
            [ac] => 0
            [occupancy] => 
            [size] => 
            [view] => 
            [service] => 
            [terrace] => 0
            [pickup] => 0
            [internet] => 0
            [gym] => 0
            [note] => 
            [room_details] => 
        )

)
```

I want to echo the per images under room_details to show like this

> images/logo2.png 
>   images/logo.png

Here's my code

```
    foreach ($roomandsuits as $i => $item) { 

      $array_links = json_decode($item->room_details, true); { 

        foreach  ($array_links as $key => $value) {   

          foreach ($value as $content) { 

       echo $content; 

       }           
       }     
      } 
     }
```

Error in 3rd line and shows like this

```
images/logo2.png
images/logo.png
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\resort\modules\mod_roomandsuits\tmpl\default.php on line 10
>   images/logo.png

Comment: Why there is an opening bracket in the 2nd line?

Comment: Can you post the definition for $roomandsuites? Is it the array you have posted?

Comment: I've posted an answer to address the immediate question. My suggestion however would be to avoid the heavy nesting of loops. In the example you posted you're three levels deep. You may want to look at some of the array functions PHP has to offer. Generic variable names aren't doing you any favours either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  the below code. I added the details with comments.

```
foreach ($roomandsuits as $i => $item) { 

        if($item->room_details){  //check if value of $item->'room_details' not null

            $room_details = json_decode($item->room_details, true); //decode the json data

            if(!empty($room_details)){  //Check if room_details is not empty array
                $room = $room_details['img'];
                array_walk($room, function($value){  //using array_walk gate the value of room_details
                    echo $value .'<br/>';
                });

            }
        }

    }
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/j2WYD)

Comment: This will output an extra/unneeded trailing `<br>`.  There is no need to declare `$i`.

Comment: @mickmackusa, file save with .php, and run it br will not come

Comment: You are echoing `<br>` after every `$value`.  The `<br>` will come.

Comment: @mickmackusa, no that tool is for php only so it's coming in HTML output.

Comment: I am worried that you don't know what your script is doing.

Comment: @mickmackusa, see the actual output  in web- https://www.screencast.com/t/DKHrAaXS

Comment: I'm asking you to think about your script.  Now show me a screenshot of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check you're working with an array before passing it to `foreach`.

The second element in `$roomandsuits` has an empty 'room_details'. Regardless, you're putting it through `json_decode()` and immediately passing to foreach.

```
$array_links = json_decode($item->room_details, true); // there was a misplaced opening brace here previously...

if (!is_array($array_links)) {
    continue;
}

foreach ($array_links as $key => $value) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deep json strings are structurally different.  Decoding the first generates an `img` keyed array containing two strings.  The second has is null or an empty string (your post doesn't reveal that for us).  Your final `foreach()` is trying to iterate a non-iterable data type -- this is the cause of your issue.

---

I might suggest a refactor to avoid so many `foreach()` structures...

You can isolate the `room_details` column with `array_column()` after casting the input array as an array.

It is important that you not only check that the subarray is not empty, but that it actually contains the `img` key.  If it does, my script will assume that it is an indexed array.

Then iterate the collection of json strings, decode them, then unpack (with the splat operator `...`) and push them into your result array.

When finished building the result array, implode the elements with `<br>`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LcQNN))

```
$array = [
    (object)[
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'delux',
        'room_details' => '{"img":["images/logo2.png","images/logo.png"]}'
    ],
    (object)[
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'hjghj',
        'room_details' => ''
    ]
];

$images = [];
foreach (array_column((array)$array, 'room_details') as $json) {
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    if (isset($obj->img)) {
        array_push($images, ...$obj->img);
    }
}

echo implode("\n", $images);  // implode with <br> for html linebreaks
```

Output:

```
images/logo2.png
images/logo.png
```

One advantage of using `array_column()` is if `room_details` does not exist for some reason in one of the objects, it will be omitted from the looping process.  This avoids the need to check if `room_details` `isset()` before trying to decode it.

Comment: with implode, You can not add more details with image name. like class id etc. It will just display the image, better to use loop and display the image.

Comment: You are creating an issue that is not mentioned in the OP's question.  I am answering the OP's question perfectly.

Comment: let's decide the OP

Comment: Let the OP decide what?  If I am right?  I know this is right because I tested it myself.  This isn't my first day as a programmer.

Comment: Looks like extra white space to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197108/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-mickmackusa).